# Getting an instagram picture/video based on the hashtag

Tags: api, instagram, hashtag

I want to know if it is possible to get photos and videos from instagram with a specific hashtag to post on a website I'm developing. I searched other questions before and I and I got a partial answer. I was referred to the Instagram API endpoints but no other questions were answered about getting pictures and videos based on a specific hashtag/tag. I'm new to this so I may be missing some obvious things but I'm willing to learn all I can about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C,

You must call

https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/YOUR_TAG/media/recent?access_token=YOUR_TOKEN

Where YOUR_TAG is the tag you are looking for and YOUR_TOKEN is the access token.

More about the media/search endpoint you can found at: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/

You will need write a code to get it, and read the json it returns.